# Kotlin application.yml data class looking for beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-properties, configurationproperties

I have a Kotlin data class that I want to read properties from `application.yml` file.  Here is my data class:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("meanwhile.in.hell.myapp")
data class MyAppProperties(val serverId: String, val locationId: String)
```

I then added it to my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppProperties::class)
open class MyAppConfiguration(private val properties: MyAppProperties) {
```

where I access the values using just `properties.serverId` and pass the object into the constructor of other beans being created, such as this one:

```
open class MyAppClient(
    private val webClient: WebClient,
    private val properties: MyAppProperties
) : IMyAppClient {
```

However, when I start up my application I get an error that instead of trying to load the properties from `application.yml`, it is trying to find beans for the constructor params:

`Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'meanwhile.in.hell.myapp-meanwhile.in.hell.myapp.MyAppProperties': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

`Parameter 0 of constructor in meanwhile.in.hell.myapp.MyAppProperties required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.`

How do I stop my app thinking that these params are Autowired?  I know that in Kotlin, this is how a constructor Autowired bean looks like (ie, not requiring the annotation), but all example I have seen online on how to read `application.yml` properties looks the same as my data class.

Spring-Boot v2.3.0.RELEASE
Kotlin v1.3.72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the dependency

`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect`

Docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kotlin-requirements

Issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19582